# How can I find the appropriate robot footprint?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all, I'm starting out in ROS and trying to set up my nav stack correctly. I'm trying to figure out on how to specify my robot's footprint and request some help. Thank you :D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385798/how-can-i-find-the-appropriate-robot-footprint?/) by [ROS_newbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/79161/ros_newbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to set up the footprint of a "non-comercial" robot (DIY) you should write down the coordinates on the common costmaps yaml.
I have a rectangular sized robot with the base_link frame at the center of that rectangle, so I have 4 coordinates written in counterclockwise direction.
So, for example, if I have something like this:

[image: image description]

My footprint should be: [[-10, -20], [10, -20], [10, 20], [-10,20]].

Hope this can help you!

---

Originally posted by [Ronro](https://answers.ros.org/users/81242/ronro/) with karma: 46 on 2021-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROS_newbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/79161/ros_newbie/) on 2021-09-08**:
Thank you for the clear explanation!

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-09-08**:
For `move_base`, these values should be in units of **meters**. @Ronro Your example shows a very, very large robot.

**Comment by [Ronro](https://answers.ros.org/users/81242/ronro/) on 2021-09-08**:
Yeah! You are completely right! The correct footprint should be: [[-0.1, -0.2], [0.1, -0.2], [0.1, 0.2], [-0.1, 0.2]]
Massive thanks, buddy! @MikeScheutzow

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: tf_tree]

you can find it in the urdf file of your robot

or you can simply run the following command after spawning your robot in gazebo

> `rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree`

you will find it in the top of the tf tree like in the following image "base_link" is the robot footprint.

---

Originally posted by [KroNton](https://answers.ros.org/users/57932/kronton/) with karma: 21 on 2021-09-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROS_newbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/79161/ros_newbie/) on 2021-09-08**:
I was asking about the coordinates of my robot footprint specifically, but this also helped me get a clearer view so thank you!